# WebRTC Problem/Error on Mobile Devices' Browser

Tags: mobile, websocket, socket.io, cross-browser, webrtc

I had encountered a problem here with browser WebRTC. I had try to gone through numerous atricles and still unable to find a fix and also not sure what is the main reason of the problem.

I have created a webrtc with nodejs express (socket.io). The idea of this webrtc is to have a simplified webrtc conference platform without having to install native apps.

I had built the web app and it's working flawlessly on Windows Browsers (tested on Chrome & Edge) and Apple MacBook Pro (Safari).

However, the problems come when we try on mobile devices. Currently tested on Android (Chrome) and iOS (Safari). When joining session with mobile browser, there's a weird error on audio. The audio stream from mobile seems only transmitted to certain participants. Not everyone able to hear the mobile audio stream, only some. But for video, the stream is okay without problem. After some debugging, I found that for mobile devices, it will have "WebSocket connection failed" error awhile after joining a session. And at the same time, when "WebSocket connection failed" occurs, the websocket seems to be unavailable where all emits(broadcast) is not functioning for everyone in the session.

Sorry for the long essays, as I still unable to precisely point out the main point of the cause.

The WebRTC platform can be accessed at [SkyMeet](https://www.skymeet.co)

```js
//connecting to current participants
peer.on("call", (call) => {
    const callList = [];
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraint_b).then((stream) => {
                    stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
                    call.answer(stream);
                    call.on("stream", function (remoteStream) {
                        if (!callList[call.peer]) {
                            addVideoStream(remoteStream);
                            callList[call.peer] = call;
                        }
                    });
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Failed to get local stream", err);
                });
            });
});

//connecting to newly joined user
const connectToNewUser = (socketID, streams, pid) => {
    const callList = [];
    const call = peer.call(socketID, streams);
    call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        if (!callList[call.peer]) {
            addVideoStream(userVideoStream);
            callList[call.peer] = call;
        }
    });
    call.on("close", () => {
        document.getElementById(`video_${pid}`).remove();
    });
    peers[socketID] = call;
};
```

Comment: Is there any useful error message in the Console? What have you done to isolate the issue? Does it work when the participants are just 2?

Comment: @giavac When mobile users joined and bugged, after a few moments then it looks like the socket.io is closed which will have the invalid header frame error message in console and all emits are not working.
When participant are just 2, everything is working fine on pc/mobile.

Comment: I have tried to find out a pattern on the bug. However, it seems like it's really random.
Here's what i found out:
Trial 1: 1st Joiner -> iOS A, 2nd Joiner -> Windows 11, 3rd Joiner -> iOS B | Trial 2: 1st Joiner -> iOS B, 2nd Joiner -> Windows 11, 3rd Joiner -> iOS A | Trial 3: 1st Joiner: Windows 11, 2nd Joiner -> iOS A, 3rd Joiner -> iOS B.
Errors discovered:
Trial 1 -> 2nd Joiner unable to hear 3rd Joiner audio.
Trial 2 -> 2nd Joiner unable to hear 3rd Joiner audio.
Trial 3 -> 3rd Joiner unable to hear 2nd Joiner audio, 1st Joiner unable to hear 3rd Joiner audio.